# pytest parametrize using values from a fixture

Tags: python, pytest

I have a fixture (lets call it `class_fixture`) that dynamically returns a class I wish to run tests on.

I have another fixture (lets call it `methods_fixture`) that uses `class_fixture` and returns the names of all methods (that fit a specific criteria) of that class.

I also have a test that uses both fixtures and performs certain checks all methods:

```
def test_methods(class_fixture, methods_fixture):
    for method in methods_fixture:
        # DO TESTS ON class_fixture.method, for our example, lets test method name starts with DUMMY
        assert getattr(class_fixture, method).__name__.startswith("DUMMY")
```

I would like to convert that test to be parameterized and be similar to the following:

```
def test(class_fixture, methods_fixture_as_parameter):
    # This test function should generate multiple tests, one for each method returned by `methods_fixture`
    # DO TESTS ON class_fixture.method, for our example, lets test method name starts with DUMMY
    assert getattr(class_fixture, methods_fixture_as_parameter).__name__.startswith("DUMMY")
```

I tried going over pytest's parametrize documentation and couldn't find anything that fits. Since `methods_fixture` depends on a different fixture, I can't seem to implement what I want (because I assume I don't have the list of methods at test-creation time).

I couldn't get it to work with `indirect`, although it might be possible.

I also tried adding a `pytest_generate_tests` hook, but couldn't reach the values of `methods_fixture` or `class_fixture` to actually set the parameter values.